# A linear function $l$ on continuous space $C[0,1]$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider the space of continuous function on $[0,1]$, that is $C=C([0,1])$. Then any linear functional $l$ on $C$ is always continuous ? I think so, but no simple idea to proved.

Comment: You should specify what the norm of the space is.

Comment: I think this is addressed in [Discontinuous Linear Maps (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuous_linear_map), where it gives a proof that any infinite dimensional topological vector space admits a discontinuous linear functional.

Comment: oh... so sad...

Comment: We pick a non continuous polynomial p and a certain point a in [0,1]. We take T(f)=f convolution p to get a polynomial and take its derivative at a. Now we take sequence of cont functions that gets steeper near a but keep the same value at a  and take the convolution with p then  this way we get higher derivatives going to infinity and so T(f ) is linear but not continuous.